# Google Apps authentication for App Engine boilerplate gives error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps, boilerplate

I'm trying to learn how to set up a web application using the [Google App Engine Boilerplate](http://appengine.beecoss.com/) that will restrict access to people logging in via our Google Apps domain.

I've downloaded the GAE Boilerplate, and it runs locally and on appspot. To limit login access, I did the following:

1. In Administration/Application Settings, I set Authentication Type to Google Apps Domain, and specified our domain name (xyz.com) as the Authentication Domain.
2. In `config/production.py`, which I've confirmed via `app_name` edits is being loaded properly by the server, I set `'enable_federated_login' : False,`.

But when I push the app and load it, I see the following puzzling error:

```
You must enable Federated Login Before for this application.
Google App Engine Control Panel -> Administration -> Application Settings -> Authentication Options
```

This error is coming from `boilerplate/lib/basehandler.py`, and it appears I'm getting a `NotAllowedError`.

Could someone point me at the proper process for setting up this boilerplate to work with Google Apps authentication? Thanks!

Comment: Which urls produce this error?

Comment: any of them, Proppy. I've been able to build and run other GAE code that requires Google Apps login, without seemingly a problem. It does seem to be specific to the boilerplate.